# How to affect all children by just modifying the Parent in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, parent-child

I have a jPanel `panelA` which contains jButtons, jLabels and any other stuff.
My question is, if I can set all those components inside `panelA` as children, how can I make a method like

```java
panelA.setEnable(false);
```

that makes all children disabled as well, without having to list each and everyone of them?

Is there any way in which this can be generalized to other methods in java.Swing like `panelA.setVisible(false);`?

Comment: Calling `setVisible(false)` on a `JPanel` hides the panel and all its contents. Did you try it? Regarding `setEnabled()`, it can't be done without iterating through all the components contained in the `JPanel`.

Comment: @Abra Yes you are right, I had tried it. But my main intention here is to generalize to more methods.

Comment: Even if you wrote your own container class that extends `java.awt.Component`, I think you would still have to iterate through all the components contained in that container.

Comment: @NassifVisuals did my answer helped? tell me if you want more info or help

Comment: @Amoun I have set your answer as accepted. It was truly helpful, and rightnow I was implentening it to my code. I have found it pretty excellent idea!

Comment: @NassifVisuals happy to hear that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no predefined function, but you can creat one like following :

```
void setPanelEnabled(JPanel panel, Boolean isEnabled) {
panel.setEnabled(isEnabled);
Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
for (Component component : components) {
    if (component instanceof JPanel) {
        setPanelEnabled((JPanel) component, isEnabled);
    }
    component.setEnabled(isEnabled);
  }
}
```